# How to make python wait for a program to stop before going to the next line of code

Tags: python3, selenium

I'm creating a script in python that will open a program then python will wait for that program to close itself before continuing to the next code. Here is my script:

```
Import subprocess as sp
sp.Popen([r'C:/Folder/folder/a.exe'])
??????
????????
print("test")
```

The question marks are the things that I don't know.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Try subprocess.call instead of Popen. It waits for the command to complete.

```py
import subprocess
subprocess.call('a.exe')
print("test")
```

[For reference.](https://docs.python.org/3/library/subprocess.html#subprocess.call)

Comment: Thank you, I marked this answered becaused it work, thou I put the exact location of the exe file rather than just regular a.exe

Answer (score 5):

@Legate77's answer is correct, but for versions > 3.5, `subprocess.run` is preferred:

```
import subprocess
subprocess.run(['./a.out', 'arg1', 'arg2'])
print('done')
```

Documentation is on the same [page](https://docs.python.org/3.5/library/subprocess.html#subprocess.run)